# Find and remove quotes within table

Tags: mysql

So this is probably a stupid question and I've tried finding it within other find/replace posts but they didn't work/fit my problem.

I have a field in my table that randomly has a " at the beggining of the line and I wanted to know how I could find and remove these quotes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just guessing, but can you update your table, and set the column value to its same value without the strings?

[String Replace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME, '"', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
UPDATE tbl SET fld = SUBSTR(fld, 2) WHERE fld LIKE '"%';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the quote if it's the first character of the string then you can do something like this:

```
update your_table 
set your_column = substr(your_column,2) 
where left(your_column,1) = '"'
```